# Draw the Direction between points in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

We have json like this

`var myjson=[
    {
        "Longitude": "17.4266008",
        "Lattitude": "78.5497557",
        "UserID": "2"
    },
    {
        "Longitude": "17.4265974",
        "Lattitude": "78.5497276",
        "UserID": "2"
    },
    {
        "Longitude": "17.4266509",
        "Lattitude": "78.5496451",
        "UserID": "2 "
    },
    {
        "Longitude": "17.4266506",
        "Lattitude": "78.5497198",
        "UserID": "2"
    },
    {
        "Longitude": "17.4266805",
        "Lattitude": "78.5496888",
        "UserID": "2"
    },
    {
        "Longitude": "17.4266805",
        "Lattitude": "78.5496888",
        "UserID": "2"
    },
    {
        "Longitude": "17.4266805",
        "Lattitude": "78.5496888",
        "UserID": "2"
    },
    ];`

We need Like this[image]
So We tried like this

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var waypts = [];
  var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
    if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected == true) {
      waypts.push({
          location:checkboxArray[i].value,
          stopover:true});
    }
  }

  var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
      var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
      summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
      // For each route, display summary information.
      for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
      }
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

We know only draw Lines Between two points but We have json.In json have number of latitude and longitude .We need to Draw Lines Between points.Please guide me.And tell me what wrong in my code. `calcRoute` method is called in button action

Comment: Instead of reading the waypoints from the DOM, read them from your array instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the waypoints from the DOM, read them from your array.  Something like

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var waypts = [];

    var myjson = [{
        "Longitude": "17.4266008",
        "Lattitude": "78.5497557",
        "UserID": "2"
    }, {
        "Longitude": "17.4265974",
        "Lattitude": "78.5497276",
        "UserID": "2"
    }, {
        "Longitude": "17.4266509",
        "Lattitude": "78.5496451",
        "UserID": "2 "
    }, {
        "Longitude": "17.4266506",
        "Lattitude": "78.5497198",
        "UserID": "2"
    }, {
        "Longitude": "17.4266805",
        "Lattitude": "78.5496888",
        "UserID": "2"
    }, {
        "Longitude": "17.4266805",
        "Lattitude": "78.5496888",
        "UserID": "2"
    }, {
        "Longitude": "17.4266805",
        "Lattitude": "78.5496888",
        "UserID": "2"
    }];


    for (var i = 0; i < myjson.length; i++) {
        waypts.push({
            location: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(myjson[i].Lattitude), parseFloat(myjson[i].Longitude)),
            stopover: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: We followed as you said but We got Status ZERO_RESULTS,So ping are not displayed Please guide me